# C change sqlite prepare_stmt

Tags: c, sqlite

I have C code that creates different tables based on data being encountered in a separate operation. As a further complication, some of the data needs to be inserted into the same table as other data, and can be encountered in any order. As the data does have common indices, I am handling this using indices and UPSERT statements. Below is a simple example of the setup. The prepared statement doesn't seem to be updating as I am only getting partial insertions or none at all. I think this is related to some memory allocation on the statement?

```
// System includes
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Local includes
#include <sqlite3.h>

// Function to create the insertion string for sqlite
char* insert_string(int flag)
{
    if(flag==1)
    {
        return("INSERT INTO test(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT (a,b) DO UPDATE SET c=excluded.c, d=excluded.d");
    }
    else if(flag==2)
    {
        return("INSERT INTO test(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT (a,b) DO UPDATE SET e=excluded.e");
    }
}

// Function to create tables based on an integer flag
void create_table(int flag, sqlite3* sqldb)
{
    if(flag==1)
    {
        sqlite3_exec(sqldb, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(a integer, b integer, c real, d real, e real)", NULL, NULL, NULL);
        sqlite3_exec(sqldb, "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS sqldb_idx ON test(a,b)", NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else if(flag==2)
    {
        sqlite3_exec(sqldb, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(a integer, b integer, c real, d real, e real)", NULL, NULL, NULL);
        sqlite3_exec(sqldb, "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS sqldb_idx ON test(a,b)", NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Initialize database
    sqlite3 *sqldb;
    int sql_rc;
    sqlite3_stmt* sql_stmt;
    sqlite3_open("test.db", &sqldb);

    // Loop over some integer flags
    for(int i=1; i<3; i++)
    {
        // Create the table and begin the transaction
        create_table(i, sqldb);
        sqlite3_exec(sqldb, "BEGIN TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, NULL);

        // Prepare the insertion statement
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqldb, insert_string(i), -1, &sql_stmt, NULL);

        // Insert a different amount of data depending on the flag
        sqlite3_bind_int(sql_stmt, 1, 1);
        sqlite3_bind_int(sql_stmt, 2, 2);
        if(i==1)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_double(sql_stmt,3,1.0);  
            sqlite3_bind_double(sql_stmt,4,2.0); 
        }
        else if(i==2)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_double(sql_stmt,5,3.0); 
        }
        sqlite3_step(sql_stmt);
        sqlite3_reset(sql_stmt);

        // End the transaction
        sqlite3_exec(sqldb, "END TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    }

    // Finalize and close
    sqlite3_finalize(sql_stmt);
    sqlite3_close(sqldb);
}
```

Comment: You should pull the invariants up out of the loop (the create table stmt, the begin transaction stmt, and the call to prepare

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Yea I thought about that too. This is not contained in this particular example, as only one table is being created, but in my actual use case multiple tables are being created, so I decided to leave it in there just in case that had something to do with the behavior I am seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL you're attempting to compile isn't valid.  This will fix it:

```
    if(flag==1)
    {
        return("INSERT INTO test VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT (a,b) DO UPDATE SET c=excluded.c, d=excluded.d");
    }
    else if(flag==2)
    {
        return("INSERT INTO test VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT (a,b) DO UPDATE SET e=excluded.e");
    }
```

Note the added `VALUES` in the SQL strings.

I'd also highly recommend checking all of the outputs of `sqlite3_` calls, even in test code like this.  Doing so will show that without the change here, the first call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails with a `SQLITE_ERROR`, showing a problem with the SQL itself.

Comment: Argh, true. However, I fixed that and I am still having issues, but I think it might be because I am using an older version of sqlite that does not yet support the upsert statements. Did you have success?

Comment: Yes, the code creates a table and inserts the first set of values (you only bind 4 params, so the second upsert doesn't change any values).  I'm able to open the database in the SQLite3 shell and verify it looks good.